# Android JUnit HorizontalListView performItemClick() not working

Tags: android, junit, onitemclick

During my unit Tests I want to basically test if an Activity is started by a simple pressure on a button, that is in an `HorizontalListView`. I've already succeed in starting new Activities during previous unit test but this one is not acting as wanted. I've got an assertion failure telling me that the activity that I want to start is still null.

Actually, when I launch my unit test, it seems to not perform the click. I have to perform it **myself** during the test by using my little finger for the test to pass.

To see if I was clicking on the right View I used Logs to see which view my test was clicking and which I actually want to click: and it seems to be the right view (the right Id, the right Position and the right View). So i think the problem isn't where I'm clicking.

The Activity i'm testing is called StudioActivity and the Activity i want to start is called AddBoasterActivity.

**My Unit test method:**

```
public void testSwitchToAddBoaster(){
    assertTrue(mBoasterPreviewFragment.getWithAddButton());
    ActivityMonitor activityMonitor = getInstrumentation().addMonitor(AddBoasterActivity.class.getName(), null, false);
    mStudioActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run(){
            int lPosition = mBoasterPreviewFragment.getAdapter().getCount()-1;
            View lView = mBoasterPreviewFragment.getBoaster().getChildAt(lPosition);

            //HERE ARE LOGS TO SEE IF MY TEST IS PERFORMING 
            //THE CLICK ON THE RIGHT VIEW AT THE GOOD POSITION
            Log.i("TEST POSITION:", ""+lPosition);
            Log.i("TEST ID: ",""+lView.getId());
            Log.i("TEST VIEW: ", ""+lView);
            //AND IT'S THE GOOD VIEW!

          mBoasterPreviewFragment.getBoaster().performItemClick(lView,lPosition,lView.getId());
        }
      });       
    AddBoasterActivity lAddBoasterActivity = (AddBoasterActivity) getInstrumentation().waitForMonitorWithTimeout(activityMonitor,5000);        
    assertNotNull(lAddBoasterActivity); //HERE IS THE FAILURE, THE ACTIVITY HASN'T BEEN STARTED

    mWFBoasterPreviewFragment = new WeakReference<BoasterPreviewFragment>((BoasterPreviewFragment) lAddBoasterActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_preview));
    mBoasterPreviewFragment = mWFBoasterPreviewFragment.get();    
    assertNotNull(mBoasterPreviewFragment);

    lAddBoasterActivity.finish();
}
```

**The OnItemClickListener:**

```
mBoaster.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    if (withAddBoasterButton) {
        mBoaster.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (position == mAdapter.getCount() - 1) {
                    //HERE IS THE CURRENT VIEW
                    Log.i("POSITION:", ""+position);
                    Log.i("ID: ",""+id);
                    Log.i("VIEW: ", ""+view);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), AddBoasterActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(AddBoasterActivity.EXTRA_BOASTER_SELECTED, mSelectedUsers);
                    intent.putExtra(AddBoasterActivity.EXTRA_IS_STREAM, isStream);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, AddBoasterActivity.REQUEST_CODE_ACTIVITY);
            }
        }});
    }
```

Performing manually a click is quite embarrassing for tests which have to be automated. So if someone has any idea why it is acting like this.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally found it... just a night to sleep and it was okay. I should have think about it earlier, but **Robotium** already helped me a few times ago.

Check it out if you haven't test it yet: https://code.google.com/p/robotium/

So here's how it looks like with Robotium:

```
public void testSwitchToAddBoaster(){
    Solo solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
    ActivityMonitor activityMonitor = getInstrumentation().addMonitor(AddBoasterActivity.class.getName(), null, false);
    assertTrue(mBoasterPreviewFragment.getWithAddButton());

    int lPosition = mBoasterPreviewFragment.getAdapter().getCount()-1;
    View lView = mBoasterPreviewFragment.getBoaster().getChildAt(lPosition);

    solo.clickOnView(lView); //SIMPLE CLICK

    AddBoasterActivity lAddBoasterActivity = (AddBoasterActivity) getInstrumentation().waitForMonitorWithTimeout(activityMonitor,5000);        
    assertNotNull(lAddBoasterActivity); //NOW THE ACTIVITY IS STARTED

    mWFBoasterPreviewFragment = new WeakReference<BoasterPreviewFragment>((BoasterPreviewFragment) lAddBoasterActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_preview));
    mBoasterPreviewFragment = mWFBoasterPreviewFragment.get();    
    assertNotNull(mBoasterPreviewFragment);

    lAddBoasterActivity.finish();
}
```